# Injecting Dependencies into a Factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, factory

Just starting to to use Autofac & i'm not sure how to deal with a situation I hit correctly. I have a factory where the type I pass back has a dependency on an interface i'm injecting with autofac. Here is my autofac config for the specific component i'm having an issue with:

```
builder.RegisterType<EmployerFunctions>().As<IEmployerFunctions>();
```

Here is a factory where i'm having the issue:

```
public static IMetaDataSaver GetMetaDataFactory(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.IsReciprocal())
    {
        return new ReciprocalMetaDataSaver();
    }
    else
    {
        return new EmployerMetaDataSaver(); //<--error is here
    }
}
```

The constructor of `EmployerMetaDataSaver()` has an `IEmployerFunctions` passed in. I could be lazy of course and new up a new `EmployerFunctions` but i don't want to do that.

Comment: Are you worried about not necessary constructor parameter in your factory?

Comment: @VadimMartynov sorry i don't quite understand the question.

Comment: I have the same problem with your question. You can just add `IEmployerFunctions` to the factory's constructor or to the method if you are using delegate factory. And what is your problem?

Comment: The best way is with [Autofac delegate factories](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create [delegate factory](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) for `IMetaDataSaver` objects:

```
builder.RegisterType<EmployerFunctions>().As<IEmployerFunctions>();
builder.Register<Func<HttpRequestMessage, IMetaDataSaver>>(delegate(IComponentContext context)
    {
        if (request.IsReciprocal())
        {
            return new ReciprocalMetaDataSaver();
        }
        else
       {
           IComponentContext cc = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
           var functions = cc.Resolve<IEmployerFunctions>();
           return new EmployerMetaDataSaver(functions); //<--error is here
       }
    });
```

If you need to create `IMetaDataSaver` for `HttpRequestMessage` you can resolve delegate factory and call it with concrete `HttpRequestMessage` object:

```
// example with the explicit use container. Use DI instead in real code
Func<HttpRequestMessage, IMetaDataSaver> factory = container.Resolve<Func<HttpRequestMessage, IMetaDataSaver>>();
var dataSaver = factory(requestMessage);
```

Also, you can use ordinary factory and DI for it:

```
builder.RegisterType<EmployerFunctions>().As<IEmployerFunctions>();
builder.RegisterType<MetaDataSaverFactory>().As<IMetaDataSaverFactory>();
```

Factory class will look something like next one:

```
public interface IMetaDataSaverFactory
{
    IMetaDataSaver GetMetaDataFactory(HttpRequestMessage request);
}

public class MetaDataSaverFactory : IMetaDataSaverFactory
{
    private IEmployerFunctions _functions;
    public MetaDataSaverFactory(IEmployerFunctions functions)
    {
        _functions = functions;
    }

    public static IMetaDataSaver GetMetaDataFactory(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request.IsReciprocal())
        {
            return new ReciprocalMetaDataSaver();
        }
        else
        {
            return new EmployerMetaDataSaver(_functions); 
        }
    }
}
```